# Weird stretching in pose mode

Tags: modeling, pose-mode

Here's the pose mode question.
I want to spin the soles of my feet
Why does it stretch like that?
[image]

[image]

Comment: Have you correctly painted the weights of the feet to their respective bones and nothing else?

Comment: On my screen, the weight paint seems to have gone right in. I used a mirror and both sides had the same problem.

Comment: Thank you for your response, I created a dependent relationship from the beginning again, so the problem has been solved.